# How to get the result of the clone() function from javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, clone

this is my code :

```
html = "";
for (i = 0; i < id_array.length; i++){
    html = html.concat($(id_array[i]).clone(true));
}
console.log(html);
```

The `id_array` contains 3 ids of the `<tr>` tag . Instead of the html code from the ids , the result of the html variable is object object object ... Why ? How do I get the html code from this id ? 
This is my html code , it is not written by me , it is generated by JQgrid plugin. so i took a picture:

[image]

Comment: Why are you cloning if you just want the html ?

Comment: because the html() function return the html code between the <tr> and </tr> tag.

Comment: With so little code and no HTML, you make this question partly a guessing game. Please give us more relevant code and build a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com) if my answer doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your want to call `outerHTML`. In order to do it, you need the native DOM element, you can get it using `[0]` or `get(0)` :

```
var html = "";
for (i = 0; i < id_array.length; i++){
    html += $(id_array[i])[0].outerHTML; 
}
console.log(html);
```

Comment: the code before was good, I didnt check that you made an edit

Comment: You mean it was better with `$(id_array[i])[0].outerHTML;` ?

Comment: To get the native DOM element, which has the outerHTML property (which jQuery doesn't have)

Comment: Nice. I've been missing Firefox starting to support `outerHTML` sometime in the past.

Comment: @dystroy— [*outerHTML*](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/apis-in-html-documents.html#outerhtml) is in HTML5, but support may not be ubiquitous yet.

Comment: @RobG Come on... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @dystroy—only 5 browsers? ;-) I'm sure support is broader, but there are an awful lot of devices running not–so–common browsers that don't get a mention (or are wrongly identified) in browser stats. e.g. the browser in the Samsung Smart TV identifies as `Mozilla/5.0(SMART-TV;X11;Linux i86) AppleWebKit/534.7(KHTML, like Gecko)Versionn/5.0 Safari/534.7`, does that support outerHTML? The Adobe "get Flash" page thinks it's "Linux 32-bit, English, Safari".

Answer (score 2):

[`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) returns jQuery *objects*. You don't want to concat them with an empty string. Instead, use an array to store them:

```
trs = [];
for (i = 0; i < id_array.length; i++){
    trs.push($(id_array[i]).clone(true));
}
console.log(trs);
```

You don't want to use HTML strings when dealing with the DOM.

Comment: Beat me to it. Does the OP want the outer HTML? I don't know.

Comment: BTW, `$(id_array[i])` might need to be `$('#' + id_array[i])`, the OP hasn't shown what the content of *id_array* is, so if it's just the ID then….

Answer (score 1):

It seems you may want the outer HTML of the TR elements. Some browsers support it, but not all (and surprisingly not jQuery). In this case you can do something like:

```
var id_array = ['tr0','tr1','tr2'];
var html = "";
var tbody = $('<tbody>');

for (i = 0; i < id_array.length; i++) {
  tbody.append($('#' + id_array[i]).clone(true));
  html += tbody.html();
  tbody.html('');
}
```